# "No user interaction allowed" When running AppleScript in python

Tags: python, applescript

I have the applescript which will displays menu list and allow user to select menu items etc. 
It runs fine by itself. And now I try to run it in python. I get the No user interaction allowed. (-1713) error.

I looked online. I tried the following:

1. add on run function in the same applescript,  so what i did is just add the main into the run

   on run 
    tell application “AppleScript Runner”
     main()
    end tell
   end run
2. i tried to run the above in python 
   import os
   def main():
     os.system ('osascript -e "tell application "ApplesScript Runner" do script /Users/eee/applescript/iTune.scpt end tell"')

   if **name** == '**main**':
      main() 
   Neither way works. Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a common mistake. When you run a script using OSAScript from a shell, as you are doing, then you must tell an application to show any "display dialogs" or "choose list dialogs" or anything that requires user interaction. OSAScript can't show them so tell an app like the Finder to show them. Use code like this...

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    display dialog "Now it works!"
end tell
```

Or from the command line notice this won't work...

```
osascript -e 'display dialog "Now it will not work."'
```

But this will work since we tell the Finder to do it...

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e 'activate' -e 'display dialog "Now it works!"' -e 'end tell'
```

So bottom line is that somewhere in your iTune.scpt you are displaying a dialog. In that script just tell iTunes or the Finder to display them.

Comment: Another way to solve this is to use a 'Framework' build of Python in which case it can be it's own GUI app to host the dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was an app with `LSBackgroundOnly = YES` set attempting to run an AppleScript that displays UI, such as `display dialog ...`

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
>
> AppleScript.scpt: execution error: No user interaction allowed. (-1713)

Using `tell application "Finder" ...` or etc. works, as shown in the other answer.

Or, remove the `LSBackgroundOnly` key to enable UI AppleScripts without telling a different Application.

`LSUIElement` presents a similar mode - no dock icon, no menu bar, etc. - but DOES allow UI AppleScripts to be launched.